# coalescing multiple values for a single employee no

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as below:

```
empId appid rolename contextname contextvalue  fromdate      todate
'1234' 1     admin    manage       view        2015-01-08    2015-31-08
'1234' 1     admin    company      US          2015-01-08    2015-31-08
'5678' 2     auditor  action       audit       2015-01-08    2015-15-08
'5678' 2     auditor  report       view        2015-01-08    2015-10-08
```

I gave to show the result as below

```
empid  appid  rolename   context1       context2   fromdate       todate
'1234'  1      admin    manage:View    company:US  2015-01-08    2015-31-08
'5678'  2      auditor  action:Audit     NA        2015-01-08    2015-15-08
'5678'  2      auditor    NA           report:view 2015-01-08    2015-10-08
```

I have tried `stuff` and `coalesce` function already but the data I have is huge (10000 records).
kindly help..

Comment: Whence are those `NA` values for empid `'5678'` ?

Comment: NA is to be shown where the employee no is similar, and if no 2 contextname is present for a given time interval

Comment: In case of 1234  empid, why there is not NULL in result set? as you said, empid is similar. @sql2008

Comment: from date and to date is same for 1234 empid

Comment: @sql2008. i am trying this on [SQL Fiddle][http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a1e68/13] . Help me there.